# .htaccess Image source redirection from http to https

Tags: .htaccess

I am attempting to change http to https for an image tag through an .htacess file.

here is the source tag

```
<img src="http://www.example.org/images/post_images/5879.jpg" width="510" height="315">
```

I want to change this to:

```
<img src="https://www.example.org/images/post_images/5879.jpg" width="510" height="315">
```

here is my .htaccess file what i have accomplished so far:

```
 RewriteRule ^images/(.*) https://example.org/images/$1 [R]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^images/.+$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```